# upload image with wordpress rest api

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

I am having trouble uploading an image with the WordPress REST API (WP-API). Can someone provide some sample code. Basically I have an image that I got from a service and I'm showing in an `<img>` tag. Now I need to take that image and save it in the media library using javascript.

Alternatively (not using WP-API) if there is a plugin that would do that, I can pass the url for the image to get is saved in the media library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wp_insert_attachment` if API is not preferred. [Source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)

Ignore the `$parent_post_id` if the media library is not post specific.

You can retrieve the image url using this trick: [Retrieve images](http://bavotasan.com/2009/retrieve-the-first-image-from-a-wordpress-post/) and then use the variable for `$filename`

```
// $filename should be the path to a file in the upload directory.
$filename = '/path/to/uploads/2013/03/filename.jpg';

// The ID of the post this attachment is for.
$parent_post_id = 37;

// Check the type of file. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
$filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

// Get the path to the upload directory.
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

// Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
$attachment = array(
 'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
 'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
 'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
 'post_content'   => '',
 'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);

// Insert the attachment.
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id );

// Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

// Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

Comment: Can you help me to do the same thing in Ruby?

Comment: Nishant, I have not used an API for the answer. Not sure about Ruby :)

Comment: In the rest api, wrap include of image.php in a function_exists. Normally that is only included in the admin (vs frontend), but I am seeing it included in the rest api as well, so you may get errors depending on your usage. `if ( ! function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata') ) { require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' ); }`